# ASP.NET, C# - Creating a Navigation Dropdown Menu Bar with asp LinkButtons

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Below is the main code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Webwite1.Site1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/99d54f1718.js"></script>
    <link href="css/customstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        
       
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-lg" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage.aspx">
                    <img src="imgs/books.png" width="30" height="30" />
                    Website Test
                </a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="homepage.aspx">Home</a>
                        </li>
     
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Internships</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Research</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Jobs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clubs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Social</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">MyPages</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Other</a>
                        </li>
                       
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton4_Click">View Books</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">User Login</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Sign Up
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton3_Click" Visible="False">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton7_Click" Visible="False">Hello user</asp:LinkButton>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </nav>
        </div>


        <!-- Main Content Placeholder -->
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Content Placeholder -->

         <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div id="footer1" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                        <p>
                            <center><asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton6_Click">Admin Login</asp:LinkButton></center>
                            &nbsp;
                         
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton11" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton11_Click" Visible="False">Author Management</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton12" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton12_Click" Visible="False">Publisher Management</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton8" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton8_Click" Visible="False">Book Inventory</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton9" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton9_Click" Visible="False">Book Issuing</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                             <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton10" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton10_Click" Visible="False">Member Management</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;


                        </p>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer3" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                        <p>
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton5_Click">About Us</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton13" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton13_Click">Version History</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton14" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton14_Click">Contact Information</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton15" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton15_Click">Donate</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton class="footerlinks" ID="LinkButton16" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton16_Click">Report Issues</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;


                            
                        </p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
           </div>

            <div id="footer2" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                        <p style="color:whitesmoke">Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                 
        </footer>
        <!-- ./Footer -->

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS file that goes with the main code

```
 .footerlinks {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.footerlinks:hover {
    color: #ffd800;
}

#footer2 {
    background: #0e47e3;
}

#footer3 {
    background: #40d90d;
}

#footer1 {
    background: #870ee3;
}

.badge-primary {
    color: #ebeef0;
    background-color: #B23CFD;
}

.card-body{
    min-height: 800px;
}

.short-context{
    min-height:400px;
}
```

In the main section, there is code:
<asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton4_Click">View Books</asp:LinkButton>

I am trying to create a dropdown menu with several responsive buttons labeled A, B, C. Once you hover over "View Book", the options A, B, and C should show up.

I know how to do this in regular HTML without the ASP.net buttons.

Is there anyway to create a dropdown menu with the ASP buttons?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of "where" or "why" the confusing comes from in regards to asp.net controls such as a button, or a link button vs that of html markup?

I don't "much" see how these 2 issures are related to the question.

You have a bootstrap menu.

so, the simple question then is how can I have a drop drop trigger automatic on hover as opposed to having to click on that menu?

so, say this menu:

(I skpped some of the menu, but you get the idea).

so this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>

        <li id="mAdmin" runat="server" class="dropdown"  ClientIDMode="Static">
            <a runat="server"  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                >Auto Buttons Dropdown Test<span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/Messages">Manage Portal Email Messages</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Staff/CurrentUsersS">Show Logged on users</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/OneMonth">Month Logon Summary</a></li>

                <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/EditChoices">Change/Edit Issue tracker choices</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/SetUp">Developer site settings</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="hasproof()">My Proofs - testing</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/Issues">Issues Tracker and to-do list</a></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton Test</asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, the LAST choice is a "typical" and "standard" and "plain jane" example of a drop down in a bootstrap menu bar. (gain, ZERO to do with asp.net).

So, above results in this:

(note how I HAVE to click on the drop down).

[image]

However, you can have/set/enjoy the menu to drop down on hover.

Just add this style into the page

```
<style>
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0; /* remove the gap so it doesn't close */
    }
</style>
```

Now, I don't have to click on the menu - just a hover will drop the menu bar, so it now works/looks like this:

[image]

And as your markup show, you "already" have some link buttons with a click event. And that looks rather fine also. (you can use a button, but the menu formatting applies MUCH better if you using a link button as your example shows. You still get/have/can/enjoy a click event, so it really now just a asp.net button.

So, the bootstrap menu, the goal and want of a "auto drop down" is really much 100% un-attached to the fact that this is asp.net.

it still mostly html, and a boostrap menu, and thus it does not really care if you have a standard "a" link, or a link button for that menu. However all those issues don't change the simple goal and question:

I want the drop down menu in the menu bar to automatic expand on hover.

Adding the above simple style to that page should thus then trigger, result in the menu drop down expanding without you having to click on that drop down you add/placed into the menu bar.

Comment: You have me now very confused. If you change the dropdown to a button, then it not a drop down anymore? We had a dropdown that you had to click on to expand, and now we have that dropdown auto-expand on hover. And each option in the drop list can be  button. But, if the drop down is now a button, it not a dropdown anymore and there is nothing to expand, or even would expand, or want to expand, and it would not be a dropdown anymore, but a button. I mean, sure, if you don't want a drop down, you can have a button on the main menu - but we now not talking about a dropdown anymore, are we?